# How to build a package out of a class

Tags: python, class, constructor, package

I have written a class called editClass which works fine. The class is completely defined in the file editClass.py. The constructor is given by:

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    self.File=filename
```

I want now to build a package that only contains this class. In future of course also other classes... I spend some time on google and here searching how exactly this works but I have reached some kind of dead end. What I have so far are the following files

```
setup.py
edit/__init__.py
edit/editClass.py
```

The class definition in editClass remained untouched and works. The init only contains:
    from editClass import editClass
and the setup is

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='edit',
     version='0.1.0',
     packages=['edit'],
     author='my name'
     )
```

I installed this with $python setup.py install in the shell. This seemed to work. In a test file test.py I want to call the constructor of editClass. But

```
import edit
filename= "name.txt"
test=edit.editClass(filename)
```

does not work. The error massage is:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'editClass'

I do not know if I referred to the constructor worngle or if the problem is already in the installed package. I to be honest, I don't even know how to check.

edit: Since 
    from edit import editClass
does nor work either, I believe the problem is in the definition of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code structure, you need to change

```
import edit
filename= "name.txt"
test=edit.editClass(filename)
```

to

```
import edit.editClass
filename = "name.txt"
test = edit.editClass.editClass(filename)
```

What you've actually got is a package called `edit`, containing a module called `editClass` containing a class called `editClass`. So your import needs to import the module (`edit.editClass`) and you then need to qualify the class with it's module name. Alternatively you can do

```
from edit.editClass import editClass
filename = "name.txt"
test = editClass(filename)
```

On the other hand, if what you were trying to achieve was for your client code to look as you had it, then you need to put the `editClass` class definition into a file called `edit.py`.

Comment: If I do this I get    ImportError: No module named editClass

Comment: @Glostas which one causes a problem for you? I've outlined three ways of achieving what you want to achieve. Is it the last one? Because that involves changing your setup.py, which I didn't mention.

Comment: I did only try the first two methods. Same error message in both cases

Comment: It sounds like Python's not recognising editClass as a module. Check that the module was installed correctly and that there's an __init__.py in it.

Comment: I do not know why, but the code I posted yesterday works now. Maybe there was something strange in the RAM or something...